# prettify text, escape characters

Tags: characters, prettify-symbols-mode, character-composition

I have

```
 (appendq! prettify-symbols-alist '(
           ("_\\infty" .    (? (bl . cl) ?∞))     ;; works
           ("_{-\\infty}" . (? (bl . cl) "-∞"))   ;; does not work
 ))
```

to prettify the text `_{-\infty}` to `-∞` in a subscript (I am writing LaTeX). While the first works, the second does not work. Presumably something’s wrong with escape characters, but I could not find the flaw. Any help appreciated.

Thanks to the response below, this works:

```
           ("_\\infty" .    (? (bl . cl) ?∞))
           ("_{-\\infty}" . (? (bl . cl) ?- (br . cl) ?∞))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've used a list for your CHARACTER argument, regarding which `compose-region` tells you:

> If it is a vector or list, it is a sequence of alternate characters and
> composition rules, where (2N)th elements are characters and (2N+1)th
> elements are composition rules to specify how to compose (2N+2)th
> elements with previously composed N glyphs.

So your elements have to be characters and composition rules, whereas `"-∞"` is a string, not a character.

No doubt you will want to decide how you want to compose the individual characters of that string, and use the appropriate composition rule between them.